# developing virtual oscilloscope C #

Tags: c#, user-interface, charts, signal-processing

I am new to GUI development and Embedded programming using DSP Processors.

I would like to build a GUI of 4 channel oscilloscope using Visual C# and Windows Forms. The signals will be communicated from DSP processor using serial port RS232.

What kind of Windows Forms controls help in building such a GUI? and how to start with the work?

If there any other useful tools to be used along with Visual studio C#?
Any useful links explaining the basics of development may be helpful.

Comment: Why people are still using WinForms for new work instead of the superior WPF I have no idea. Laziness I assume.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of Windows forms controls help in building such a GUI?

There is a nice tool un Windows Forms called [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx). You can draw graphs of different kind with it.

Here is a [Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx)

Here is a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82jnryBxsnI) that shows how to use it.

> How to start with the work?

You should start and play with this control.

- Learn how to add values.
- Learn how to remove values.
- Learn how to bind values.
- Learn how to handle the axes and the ranges to be displayed.

> If there any other useful tools to be used along with Visual studio C#?Any useful links explaining the basics of development may be helpful.

here you find all different [chart types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489233.aspx) that can be displayed.

and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456769.aspx) how to use them.

This answer is partly copied from a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713649/how-could-i-display-a-graph-on-windowsforms/38713920#38713920) one of mine.

I would suggest to search also for "online/real time display of data with chart control" or "moving chart".

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/93820/Draw-a-realtime-graph-in-C-for-Serial-port-data) might be usefull. It asks for almost the same as you.

Here you can find some [samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Comment: Really good answer, thanks.

Comment: No problem. Have fun!  I sure did :)

Comment: Thank you so much.I shall try out and get back.

Comment: @ Mong Zhu -Can the look of the graph generated using zedgraph be improved? Currently the background of the graph is white.Can it be changed to say, black, with green dotted grid lines, similar to an oscilloscope view?

Comment: @user6708463 for the background color, the first answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997690/change-zedgraph-pane-background-color) should help. For the grid lines color try: `myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.DashOff = 1` and 
`myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.Color = Color.Green`. it's from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683563/zedgraph-majorgrid-and-minorgrid-linestyle). ( I personally never used zedgraph)